# problem after merge shapefiles, can't show it on OpenLayers with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, merge

I have 5 .shp files, after merge it with geomerge, I can't use it on OpenLayers with GeoServer. it's only show white layer and when i click it, it show error message:
Internal error occurred ShapeType changed illegally from Arc to Point . what should I do?

Comment: could you give a shapefile example, maybe? It would be easier to answer your question. It does not have to be whole dataset, only part of it.

Comment: To add to what @MarioMiler said, it would be useful to include portions of each of the input datasets, to see what was being combined.

Comment: it was ordinary shape file for street data.. thx for the help, it's working now

Answer (score 2):

The [shapefile specification](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) does not allow you to mix different types of shape in a single shapefile.

I've never heard of geomerge but it probably shouldn't allow you to do that as the end file won't be usable.

If you need all five files in a single WMS layer for some reason then look at layergroups instead.

Comment: but i was same format, for street place. when I open it with Quantum gis it's normal, when I export it to geoserver it's work, but when i use it to preview layers with open layer it show just white.. n when I click just error Internal error occurred ShapeType changed illegally from Arc to Point. thx for your answer :)

Comment: It means GeoMerge generated a shapefile whose ShapeType is not constant along the geometries, some are arcs, some are points. That shapefile is invalid, some software might be more or less tolerant with broken ones.

Comment: thx for the answer, I will try using another software.. what recommendation do you have to merge shapefile?

Comment: @xaver - I would definitely try [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org).  It is easy to use, and you may just find other uses for it as well.  One thing to be aware of, that was not directly addressed in the answer, is that if your shapefiles have multiple shape types, like point or polyline, you won't be able to merge them all together into one.  You can merge all the lines together and all the points together.

Comment: At first I use quantum gis but it's show error and doesn't work. so I use geomerge and it's work but doesn't work when used. after googling and change domergeshapes.py it's work with quantum gis and problem solved thx for the support :)